# Unique Sudoku Finder

Tags: code-golf, game, sudoku

## Challenge:

Given a Sudoku board on standard input, find the minimum number of numbers added to make the board unique.

### Specifics/Rules:

- The input is formatted as follows (all whitespace is significant)

  ```
  516|827|943
  278|394|615
  349|615|872
  ---+---+---
  98 |4 2|156
  465|189|237
  12 |5 6|489
  ---+---+---
  892|743|561
  634|951|728
  751|268|394
  ```
- The output is formatted with one number per line, formatted like `(x,y):z` - x and y start from one at the top left and increase down and right; z is the number to be added.

  - In this case these would all be valid outputs: `(3,4):3`, `(3,4):7`, `(5,4):3`, `(5,4):7`, `(3,6):3`, `(3,6):7`, `(5,6):3`, and `(5,6):7`, as any one of these would allow the board to be solved.
- If a unique/solved Sudoku board is entered, the program should not print anything, even a newline.
- The program should run in less than an hour for any board (I suggest testing using a fully blank board, or a board with one random number on it...).

### Scoring:

- Take your total (golfed) code size in characters, *including all whitespace*...

### Bonuses:

**1/2 code size**:  If the program prints a single exclamation point and stops upon having a board with no solutions entered.

**1/2 code size**:  If the program prints two exclamation points and stops upon having a board with an internal contradiction entered (two numbers the same on the same row/column/square).

Comment: Boring and probably difficult :(

Comment: Boo. 'Not print anything, not even a newline' rules out GolfScript.

Comment: a sudoku solver that never needs to backtrack/guess for a full solution is needed for this, (and each time a "guess" is needed output it)

Comment: I don't see the reason to downvote this. Much effort was made to show a pretty puzzle; it is very clear, and properly stated. It's too big for my taste, but that's too subjective for a reason to downvote, isn't it?

Answer (score 10):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 245 bytes /2 = 122.5

```
@n:1a:"-"x:7fF:3a$\:3a@3:4a,Fc~bCh[0:0:0]gO,Co~c[V:O:T]h:F:6f:10ao:ba(h:11a;!);"!!"w!
h"-".|:"|"x:2f.
e(~m["0123456789":.]`;0<.<=9)
:ha#d.
:@3az:ca:5a.
:3a.
hs.:=a,?t:9ac:=fl1
:Im:8f:[[I]]z:ca.
:Jm:J.
:ha.
lg:?c.
b:+a[X:Y],?h:Y:Xr:"(~d,~d):~d
"w
```

**(Note that you have to use [the version of the language as of this commit](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog/tree/8184dab5a2e041ffbe44ae2e886ad3cc53749c1d). This code would need some slight changes for it to work properly in the following versions of Brachylog)**

This prints `"!!"` if the given board has internal contradictions (This takes a few seconds in that case however on TIO, so be patient).

I'm not sure I understand the first bonus correctly so I'm not addressing it.

This is obviously non-competing since the language is much more recent than the challenge, however since there are no other answers I'm not sure this matters a whole lot…

#### Explanation

- Main predicate:

  ```
  @n                Split the input on line breaks
  :1a:"-"x          Transform into a list of lists, each sublist contains a line's values
  :7fF              Transform so that cells are [Value:X:Y]
  :3a               All values on lines must be different
  $\:3a             All values on columns must be different (by transposition)
  @3:4a,            All 3*3 block values must be different
  Fc~bCh[0:0:0]gO,  Append a fake cell [0:0:0]
  Co~c[V:O:T]       Sort the board, the blank cells V will be those before O ([0:0:0])
  h:F:6f            Find all subsets of blank cells with specific values for which 
                        the board has only one solution
  :10ao             Sort the subsets by lengths
  :ba               Discard the lengths
  (                 
    h:11a             Print the first subset = an answer
  ;                 Or (board is already fully determined)
    !                 Terminate
  )          
  ;                 Or (Some values don't respect the constraints)
  "!!"w!            Print "!!" and terminate
  ```
- Predicate 1: Remove all "`|`" on lines, transform the `---+---+---` into `-` to remove them after

  ```
  h"-".    If the first char is "-", then Output is "-"
  |        Or
  :"|"x    Remove all occurences of "|" from the input
  :2f.     Output is the result of all outputs of predicate 2 on the filtered string
  ```
- Predicate 2: Convert one char to an integer, or if blank to a variable between 1 and 9.

  ```
  e                      Take a char of the input string
  (
    ~m["0123456789":.]     Output is the index of the char in "0123456789"
    `                      Discard the choice point caused by the ;
  ;                      Or
    0<.<=9                 Output is an integer between 1 and 9
  )
  ```
- Predicate 3: Impose that all values of the input list of cells must be distinct

  ```
  :ha    Retrieve the head of each cell (i.e. the value) in the input 
  #d.    Apply a constraint of distinctness to those values
  ```
- Predicate 4: Apply the distinctness constraint to values in 3*3 blocks

  ```
  :@3a            Split 3 lines of the board in 3 parts
      z           Zip them together
       :ca:5a.    Concatenate each element of the zip, apply predicate 5 to that
  ```
- Predicate 5:

  ```
  :3a.    Apply predicate 3 to each element of the input
  ```
- Predicate 6: Assign values satisfying the constraints to a subset of the blank cells, then with those values there is only one solution to the board.

  ```
  hs.       Output is a subset of the blank cells
  :=a,      Assign values to those cells
  ?t:9ac    Concatenate the values of all cells of the board
  :=f       Find all solved boards
  l1        There is only 1 such solved board
  ```
- Predicate 7: Transforms the board such that each cell is now `[V:X:Y]` instead of only `V` (the value).

  ```
  :Im       Take the Ith line of the board
  :8f       Transform all elements of the line using predicate 8
  :[[I]]z   Zip the result with [I]
  :ca.      Concatenate each element of the zip
  ```
- Predicate 8: Transforms a line such that each cell is now `[V:X]`.

  ```
  :Jm    Take the Jth element of the line
  :J.    Output is [That element:J]
  ```
- Predicate 9: Retrieve the values of cells

  ```
  :ha.   Take the head of each element of the input
  ```
- Predicate 10: Append the length of a subset at the beginning of it

  ```
  lg     Put the length of the input in a list
  :?c.   Concatenate it with the input
  ```
- Predicate 11: Print one cell

  ```
  b:+a[X:Y],        Increment coordinates by 1 to get X and Y
  ?h:Y:Xr:          Build the list [X:Y:Value]
  "(~d,~d):~d\n"w   Format that list as "('X','Y'):'Value'\n" to STDOUT
  ```

Comment: Can’t you just expand this into a Prolog answer? Then it’d be competing! (You could post it separately.) I’m not sure how direct the mapping between Brachylog and Prolog is.

Comment: @Lynn Yes I could, I could even just post the Prolog code that gets generated by Brachylog's transpiler (which would be highly ungolfed obviously). I won't do it though because I'm pretty sure the challenge's poster will never come back to accept an answer anyway :p